# Backend no recibe petición enviada desde Ajax

Tags: ajax

Quiero llamar a un método en el back end desde ajax, este método debe llevar dos datos que son números pero los puedo mandar como string también.

Este es mi código de ajax:

```
int x = (Number(e.target.parentElement.children[1].textContent));
 int xy = (Number(e.target.parentElement.children[0].textContent));

 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "MillsData.aspx/EliminarSeleccionado",
     data: { semana: x, anio: xy },
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: OnSuccess,
     failure: function (response) {
         alert(response.d);
     }
 });
```

Y este es el método en el backend que es c#
En este método tengo un breakpoint para saber cuando entre pero nunca llega a esa parte del código.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public void EliminarSeleccionado(int semana, int anio)
        {
            int wik = semana;
            int tir = anio;
        }
```